# get name for element in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

i have the input checkbox that i display dynamically

i want to get the names of all the inputs

the parameters list contains 20 elements, the problem is that in the console it displays the first name repeated 20 times

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let parameter of category.parameters" [ngSwitch]="parameter.type">
    <label class="switch switch-small" *ngSwitchCase="'toggle'">
         <input #toggle type="checkbox" name="{{parameter.parameterId}}" formControlName="{{parameter.parameterId}}" (change)="checkboxAction(parameter.parameterId)">
         <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>                         
</ng-container>

@ViewChild('toggle') toggle: any;

save(): void {
    console.log(this.toggle.nativeElement.getAttribute('name'));
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `yourForm.value` to get the details?

Comment: @nircraft in my form i have many inputs for type checkbox, text, number... i want to get only the values of the inputs of type checkbox